# Gekko, dynamically limit lower bound of variables based on intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, gekko

For example if I have a variable f
I want the lower bound to be

- 0.1 if f < 0.25
- 0.75 if f < 1
- 1.25 if f < 1.5
- 1.7 if f >= 1.5

I've tried the following to no avail

```
limit1 = m.if3(f-0.25, 0.1, 0.25)
limit2 = m.if3(f-1,limit1, 0.75)
limit3 = m.if3(f-1.5, limit2, 1.7)
f.lower = limit3.value
f.upper = 3
```

This seems to be able to set the lower bound correctly but when I do

```
print(f.lower,"<", f.value,"<", f.upper)
```

I get `[0.1] < [constant value independent of lower bound] < 3`

Now, I have multiple variables like f in an array with differing lower bound possibilities and all have the exact same values, as if the lower bound didn't even matter

When writing

```
f.lower=f1
```

then when I print `f.lower.value` I get

```
[correct lower bound] < [upper bound] < upper bound
```

I'm probably approaching the problem wrong, so I would love some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.lower` and `.upper` values of a Gekko variable have a single value and are not adjustable by the optimizer during the iterations.

You can generate any arbitrary relationship (like a step function) with a Piecewise linear `pwl` function such as shown in the [Model Building Methods](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html). In your case, you want the `lower` bound to change as the value of `f` changes. Here is one implementation just for showing the function for `lower` as it depends on `f`:

[image: Piecewise linear function]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
f = m.Param(np.linspace(0,2,200))
lower = m.Var()

d=1e-5
x_data = [-1e5,0.25,0.25+d,1,1+d,1.5,1.5+d,1e5]
y_data = [0.1,0.1,0.75,0.75,1.25,1.25,1.7,1.7]

m.pwl(f,lower,x_data,y_data)
#m.Equation(f>=lower)

m.options.IMODE = 2
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(f,lower,'b--')
plt.plot(x_data,y_data,'ro')
plt.xlim([0,2])
plt.show()
```

I commented out the equation `m.Equation(f>=lower)` because I have `f` values that are lower than `0.1` and this creates an infeasible solution. Another way to solve this problem is to use binary variables as shown in the [discussion of logical conditions in optimization](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions). There is also an example in [APMonitor of solving piecewise discontinuous functions with binary variables](https://apmonitor.com/online/view_pass.php?f=if2b.apm).